# DocuSign: In Person Signing: Witness/host signing

Tags: docusignapi

With DocuSign In-person signing, the Host helps the signer to sign.

But along with this, can the host also sign the same document? Do we have any option for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just add another recipient to the envelope, with a signing field. One recipient is the in-person signer, the other is a signing recipient.

It is fine for one email address, (one person) to be both a signing recipient and a host for someone else to sign.

This is a common configuration. You can use routing order to determine if the host should sign before or after the in-person signing.

As part of the signing process, you can have the host-signer attest that the in-person signer's government ID was checked by the host-signer. This is a good way to take care of the issue of authenticating the in-person signer. For better admissibility, have the host-signer check a box that they made the ID check. (This is not legal advice.)